# SSL / TLS Errors on only some wifi networks

Tags: ssl, firewall

I am having problems with the SSL handshake not completing when I am on some public wifi networks. This is a problem when accessing all of the endpoints for my app, and so from some of those networks, the app just doesn't work. I have used openssl to try to test, and even that is selectively working. When I am connected to the unsecured network, this command doesn't work, and when I am on my cellular data, it does work.

```
openssl s_client -connect my_server_address.com:443
```

Here is the output from running the command on my cellular:

```
CONNECTED(00000007)
depth=2 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
verify return:1
depth=1 C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon RSA 2048 M03
verify return:1
depth=0 CN = my_server_address.com
verify return:1
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:CN = my_server_address.com
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon RSA 2048 M03
 1 s:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon RSA 2048 M03
   i:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
 2 s:C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon Root CA 1
   i:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
 3 s:C = US, ST = Arizona, L = Scottsdale, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", CN = Starfield Services Root Certificate Authority - G2
   i:C = US, O = "Starfield Technologies, Inc.", OU = Starfield Class 2 Certification Authority
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----

...

A big long body of certificate

...

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=CN = my_server_address.com

issuer=C = US, O = Amazon, CN = Amazon RSA 2048 M03

---
No client certificate CA names sent
Peer signing digest: SHA512
Peer signature type: RSA
Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits
---
SSL handshake has read 5448 bytes and written 446 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, TLSv1.2, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
    Session-ID: ---------------------Redacted----------------------
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: ---------------------Redacted----------------------
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    Start Time: 1707868579
    Timeout   : 7200 (sec)
    Verify return code: 0 (ok)
    Extended master secret: no
---
```

and on the public wifi:

```
CONNECTED(00000007)
write:errno=54
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 320 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I am looking for someone to point me in the right direction on what I need to do to make my server accessible from this public wifi network. Other websites work here, and other apps function normally (though maybe with some slight added latency) here. I noticed that all of the other apps that I tested had certificates pinned which made it so that I couldn't use my Proxyman to see into their requests to see what they did to make their requests work.

Thank you for your help.

I used Proxyman to try to investigate both requests that worked and requests that didn't.

I am really confused because the server connects just fine on almost all networks.

The problem was originally noticed on iPhone, but using this command showed that it was not a problem with ATS:

```
/usr/bin/nscurl --ats-diagnostics --verbose https://my_server_address.com
```

Comment: What kind of connection are you making when the SSL/TLS handshake is not complete?

Comment: I would suggest that some kind of DPI firewall/proxy is restricting network access in this environment and blocking your domain. That would explain that some sites work but yours don't. There is likely nothing you can do about, except checking with the ones who own this network on why your domain might be blocked.

Comment: @Turdie, The server is the backend for an iOS application. The app gets stuck on the login screen because the login request fails to make the handshake. That is an HTTPS post request.

Comment: @Steffen Ullrich, I will try checking with the network owners to clear this up and see what they say.

Comment: @Steffan Ullrich, I called the network administrator. In this case it was a public library and I was forwarded to the city IT department and they said that they don't give out any information about their firewall. (Which makes sense, but which makes my life more difficult.) It looks like I am out of luck there.